# How to get the inserted document's ID in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I'm writing a script for the mongo shell to populate some data for test.

I have two collections: `club`, and `team`, and in the team's document, it has a objectId reference to the club.

What I did is as following:

```
db.club.drop();
var club_1_id;
db.club.insert({name:'Club 1',
        venue:'Somewhere'},
    function(err, doc){
        club_1_id=doc._id;
});

db.team.drop();
var team_1_id;
db.team.insert({name:'Team 1', club:{id: club_1_id, name: 'Club 1'}}, 
    function(err, doc){
       team_1_id=doc._id;
});
```

I'm actually not so surprised to see that in the team document, the club's ID is inserted to be `null`, cause the call-back function may not be called in a timely fashion.

So in this case how can I set the id right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like:

```js
db.club.drop();
var club_1_id = new ObjectId();
db.club.insert({_id:club_1_id, name:'Club 1',venue:'Somewhere'});

db.team.drop();
var team_1_id = new ObjectId();
db.team.insert({_id:team_1_id, name:'Team 1', club:{id: club_1_id, name: 'Club 1'}});
```

Comment: While this works, I think it is wrong. You rely on an ObjectId that has not yet been added to the database. If your insert fails and you don't handle it and go on about using the ObjectId naively, then you'd have a real mess.

Answer (score 0):

```
var club_doc = {
           _id: ObjectId()
           name:'Club 1',
           venue:'Somewhere'
          } 

var id = club_doc._id;

db.club.insert(club_doc);



var team_doc = {
                 _id: ObjectId(),
                 name:'Team 1', 
                 club:{
                 id: id, 
                 name: 'Club 1'
                }
               }
var teamID = team_doc._id;
db.team.insert(team_doc);
```